# Will the cInstance hold the reference of the ActivityA object?

Tags: java, android

if another thread holds cInstance, will case memory leak of ActivityA?
code as following:

CASE 1:

```
class ActivityA{
    private void doSomething(){
        ClassB.doSomething();
    }
}
class ClassB{
    public static void doSomething(){
        ClassC cInstance = new ClassC();
        //another thread holds cInstance
    }
}       
class ClassC{}
```

CASE 2:

```
class ActivityA{
    private void doSomething(){
        ClassB.doSomething(new ClassC());
    }
}
class ClassB{
  public static void doSomething(ClassC cInstance){
      //another thread holds cInstance
  }
}
class ClassC{}
```

Comment: Method invocations cannot appear as a direct member in class bodies.

Comment: ok, I have modified it. Will?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing the subsequent history of `cInstance.`

Comment: @EJP e.g. One web thread will call a method of cInstance, after getting data.

Answer (score 0):

In case 1, it is impossible for "another thread" to "hold cInstance" because that instance is created privately inside the scope of the called method (and becomes invisible, thus eligible for GC, at the exit of the called method).

In case 2, it is impossible for "another thread" to "hold cInstance" because that instance is created privately inside the scope of the calling method (and becomes invisible, thus eligible for GC), at the exit of the calling method).

In either case, if you explicitly pass on references to cInstance inside the code of the calling/called methods, and that code results in other threads holding the reference to cInstance, then the cInstance will be held as long as needed, but this does not affect the reference count to instances of class A and/or B (unless of course class C explicitly has such references).

One case where class C holds such references by definition, is when class C is declared as an *instance* member of type Class, in class A/B.  In that case, C instances can exist only in the context of [the existence of] instances of A/B, and the C instances hold references to the members of A/B because that's how the language is defined.  But those techniques are rather advanced, so perhaps you may want to disregard such possibilities for the time being.

Answer (score -1):

We can see cInstance is instantiated in doSomething static method, so it's in static environment. Beside it, ClassB isn't an inner class of ActivityA, it won't keep reference to ActivityA. So, I think no reason that a thread holds cInstance cause a leak memory on ActivityA

Comment: thank you, I get your opinion. In CASE2, will case memory leak?

Comment: The fact that `ClassB` isn't an inner class of `ActivityA` is irrelevant.

Comment: @topcbl thank you, I get your opinion. In CASE2, will case memory leak?